# Order of array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a array A[i] with 20 numbers, and array A[i] I need to create an array B[], that consists of first 10 digits of the array A[i] and outprints them array B[] first displaying odd values and then even values.

So far I have found that I need to check if the value of i is even or odd, but I don't know how to make this order be outprinted.

```
    double A[] = new double[20];
    int i, K;
    double a;
    double B[] = Arrays.copyOf(A,10);
    List<Double> odd = new ArrayList<Double>();
    List<Double> even = new ArrayList<Double>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("XX XX XX"); 
    System.out.print("K=");
    try {
        K = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("input-output error");
        return;
    }
      if (K==0) {
           Random r = new Random();
           for (i=0; i<20; i++)
            A[i] =r.nextDouble()*20-10;
          }
          else{
           A[0]=1;
           i = 1;
           while (i<20){
            a = A[i-1];
            a = Math.toRadians(a);
            A[i] =a*K;
            i = i+1;
            }
          }
      System.out.println("A:");
      for (i=0; i<20; i++){
       System.out.printf("%.2f\t", A[i]);
       if (i==9) System.out.println();
      }
      for (i=0;i<10;i++) 
          B[i]=A[i];
      {
            if ((i % 2) == 0) {
                odd.add((double) i);
            } else {
                even.add((double) i);
            }
        }
      i=i+1;
      Collections.sort(odd);
      Collections.sort(even);
      do {System.out.println("\nB:");
        for (i=0; i<10; i++){
           System.out.printf("%.2f\t",  B[i]);
        }
      }
      while (i<10);
      }
      }
```

I get this outprint:

```
xx xxx xx

K=0

A:

-7.31   6.10    8.67    -8.92   8.10    0.08    4.50    5.94    -5.43   -1.55   
3.64    4.71    7.23    -7.80   8.35    -7.50   8.22    -2.44   8.15    5.15    
B:

-7.31   6.10    8.67    -8.92   8.10    0.08    4.50    5.94    -5.43   -1.55
```

Now it only outprints just values of A[] how can I make the B[] order that I need?

Comment: instead of using `Collections.sort(List)` use `Collections.sort(List,Comperator)` and provide a custom comperator.

Comment: @Kevin Esche is right, use [``Collections.sort(List, Comparator)``](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) to sort a list according to your needs. And btw., the usage of c-style array notation is discouraged; write ``double[] A = new double[20];`` instead...

Answer (score 0):

You probably made a mistake when putting in the brackets:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    B[i] = A[i];
{
    if ((i % 2) == 0) {
        odd.add((double) i);
    } else {
        even.add((double) i);
    }
}
```

I made a much cleaner solution for your problem, definitly have a look at it:

**Code:**

```
public class Program {
    private static final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("XX XX XX");

        int K = readInt("K");

        double[] A = new double[20]; /**/ {
            switch (K) {
                case 0:
                    Random rng = new Random();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                        A[i] = rng.nextDouble() * 20 - 10;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    A[0] = 1;
                    for (int j = 1; j < A.length; j++) {
                        double a = A[j - 1];
                        a = Math.toRadians(a);
                        A[j] = a * K;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        double[] B = new double[10]; /**/ {
            List<Double> odds = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Double> evens = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
                double value = A[i];
                if ((i % 2) == 0) {
                    odds.add(value);
                } else {
                    evens.add(value);
                }
            }
            int bi = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < odds.size(); i++, bi++) {
                B[bi] = odds.get(i);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < evens.size(); i++, bi++) {
                B[bi] = evens.get(i);
            }
        }

        printArray("A", A);
        printArray("B", B);
    }

    private static int readInt(String name) {
        while(true) {
            System.out.print(name + "=");
            String input = in.next();
            try {
                return Integer.parseInt(input);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                System.err.println("please provide a valid integer for " + name);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void printArray(String name, double[] value) {
        System.out.print(name + ":");
        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            if (i % 10 == 0) {
                //break line every 10 entries
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.printf("%10.2f\t", value[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
XX XX XX
K=0
A:
      3,28       -9,24       -9,75       -5,67        5,39        3,26       -2,99       -0,03        5,96       -0,01  
     -8,70        7,28        7,53       -1,09        2,94       -8,13       -4,29        0,50        3,38       -8,89  
B:
      3,28       -9,75        5,39       -2,99        5,96       -9,24       -5,67        3,26       -0,03       -0,01  

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: But the B line still is not in order of odd and even.
On your array A results the B should be 

[3.28 9.24 3.26 5.96 -9.75 -5.67 3.39 -2.99 -0.03 -0.01]

Comment: @Jekabs By which criteria should ``B`` be sorted? Your question stated odds then evens.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Random;

public class xxx {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double A[] = new double[20];
    int i, K, s, j;
    double a;
    double B[] = new double[20] ;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("xxx xxx");  
    System.out.print("K=");
    try {
        K = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("input-output error");
        return;
    }
      if (K==0) {
           Random r = new Random();
           for (i=0; i<20; i++)
            A[i] =r.nextDouble()*20-10;
          }
          else{
           A[0]=1;
           i = 1;
           while (i<20){
            a = A[i-1];
            a = Math.toRadians(a);
            A[i] =a*K;
            i = i+1;
            }
          }
      System.out.println("A:");
      for (i=0; i<20; i++){
       System.out.printf("%.2f\t", A[i]);
       if (i==9) System.out.println();
      }
      s=0;
      for(i=0; i<20; i++){
       j=i%2;
       if(j==0);
       else{
        B[s]=A[i];
        s++;
       }
      }
      for(i=0; i<20; i++){
       j=i%2;
       if(j==0){
        B[s]=A[i];
        s++;

       }
      }
      do {System.out.println("\nB:");
        for (i=0; i<20; i++){
           System.out.printf("%.2f\t",  B[i]);
           if (i==9) System.out.println();
        }
      }
      while (i<20);
      }
      }
```

Comment: Again, poorly formatted code, c-style array syntax, unconvential variable names, no usage of methods except ``main`` nor visible blocks of code; it's hard to read... please explain what mistakes were in and what you changed to fix them.